# Calling Stored procedure with cross apply from another stored procedure gives error SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I have been trying to call stored procedure from another stored procedure. Now issue is that under lying nested stored procedure contains CROSS APPLY with temp table and it runs fine when i execute it directly.

But when i try to call this SP from other SP, it gives error that one of the column is invalid. "Invalid column name 'levels'" in this case.

Plus, when i execute this SP from calling SP SQL window with passing parameters, it runs fine and whole main procedure starts running smoothly.

I am not able to get why this issue happens. Below is kind of implementation for reference.
1.) Main SP

```
CREATE STORED PROCEDURE ....

INSERT INTO #TempTable
EXEC [Child_SP] @Param1 = 1, @Param2 = 1
...
```

Gives error.
2.) Once i execute below given as single statement once from main PS. It starts working fine.

```
EXEC [Child_SP] @Param1 = 1, @Param2 = 1
```

3.) Child SP has CROSS APLLY with one of the temp table. something like below.

```
SELECT ID, '1,2,3,4,5' AS levels
INTO #Temp1
FROM ABC

SELECT ID
FROM #Temp1 x0
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM dbo.iter_charlist_to_table(x0.levels, ',') AS x) x1 
WHERE x1.listPos > 1
```

"iter_charlist_to_table" is table value function which get values as table from comma seperated list.

Is it related to SQL Thread anyhow or whats the issue? Thanks.

Comment: (After your first SQL) *"Gives error"*...? What error? I can't see that you've created a table before that `INSERT` either, so that is likely why.

Comment: Error is same as mentioned in post.  "Invalid column name 'levels'"

Comment: You'll need to post the full SQL then. We can't see what `Child_SP` is doing, and you have `...` on the line afterwards, implying further SQL after that `EXEC`. Don't give us snippets of your code, post the **whole** thing.

Comment: Also, you didn't answer this; do you have a `CREATE TABLE #Temptable` statement in your nameless procedure? Again, if not, then there's one problem. you can't do a `INSERT INTO [Table] EXEC [SP]` without first creating the table. `INSERT INTO` doesn't work like an `INTO` clause (i.e. `SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM [Table];`)

Comment: Larnu, yes i have CREATE TABLE mentioned already. I'll provide with exact replica of code as i can't post actual one here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use this code to drop your tmp table on the beginning of the SP because your insert INTO will ALWAYS tried to create the table doesn't matter if already exists.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Temp1
```

If you share more code will be more helpful to understand.

And just in case don't forget to put the alias on the table maybe this correction sometimes is not needed but is a good practice for avoid problems on querying the data on joined tables

```
SELECT x0.ID
FROM #Temp1 x0
CROSS APPLY (SELECT fnAlias.* FROM dbo.iter_charlist_to_table(x0.levels, ',')  fnAlias) x1 
WHERE x1.listPos > 1
```